# Get response in JSON format from @Query annotation in Spring

Tags: json, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, dto, jsonresult

Repository

```
@Repository
public interface TestNativeQRepository extends CrudRepository<TestNativeQ, String> {
    @Query( value="SELECT qplt.name price_list_name,  qplab.status_code, qplab.start_date, (SELECT charge_definition_code FROM oalfsaas_repl.QP_CHARGE_DEFINITIONS_B WHERE charge_definition_id=qplab.charge_definition_id  ) chargedefinitioncode "
            + "FROM  pricelistsall qplab, PRICELISTSTL qplt "
            + " WHERE qplab.price_list_id  =qplt.price_list_id ", nativeQuery = false)
    public List<TestNativeQDTO> getAllDetails();
}
```

Actual Result:

```
[{"ABC", "DEF", "15/05/2018", "XXZ"}]
```

Expected Result

```
[{name: "ABC", statuscode: "DEF", startDate: "15/05/2018", chargedefintioncode: "XXZ"}]
```

The Query has more than one table and also subquery at column list.

Answer (score 0):

You'll need a constructor expression:
https://javaee.github.io/tutorial/persistence-querylanguage006.html#BNBWC

E.g.:

```
SELECT NEW mypackage.TestNativeQDTO(qplt.name price_list_name,  qplab.status_code, qplab.start_date, (SELECT charge_definition_code FROM oalfsaas_repl.QP_CHARGE_DEFINITIONS_B WHERE charge_definition_id=qplab.charge_definition_id  ) chargedefinitioncode) [...]"
```

I'm not sure if it works with sub-queries, though.